# How to create a Twitter-like feed clock in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

While I've created a real-time feed for a project I'm working on, I have yet to find an effective script for quickly calculating Minutes, Hours, Days, Months since a feed story was published based on a unix timestamp.  Anybody have any ideas?

Below is an image of the feed clock I'm referencing:
[image: twitter feed clock]

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11/439187 I know it is not javascript but perhaps the answer's logic could help you, this is why I answered in a comment not as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice little plugin, use it myself.

http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: Awesome! I'll definitely implement this ... I can't vote up b/c I don't have a high enough ranking yet :(